# saving file to external server vip

Tags: filesystem, wp-remote-get, wp-remote-post

I have a handwritten script that writes a text file locally in one of my Wordpress pages, but now I need it to read and write to a remote server that is password protected and accessible only through SSH or SFTP.

I can't write to the local filesystem at all. Only the remote server.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: This is probably better off on stack overflow.

Comment: @AndrewBartel No, it isn’t. The WP HTTP API is on topic **here**.

Comment: Very good then @toscho

Comment: Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post and http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments